# 'Microsoft Exchange System Objects' container invisible in AD editor

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I can see the *Microsoft Exchange System Objects* container in the Active Directory by using ADSIEDIT.msc, but it doesn't appear in the *Active Directory Users and Computers* editor.

I can view the container's properties, and even edit a few if I wish, but I'd rather not do so at the risk of breaking my AD.

Is there a way to make it visible to the standard editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ADUC menu... View... Advanced Features

Comment: Holeee Cripes! What a simple solution and I've been fighting it for days!